# how can I update the data that I get through a https.get() request Using NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https

I get some data through a rest api (using https.get()) in nodejs , and save some of the data i get back in some variables , how can i constantly update the data

```
setInterval(function() {
  https.get(url2, (response) => {
    response.on("data", (data) => {
      const weatherData2 = JSON.parse(data);
      temp = weatherData2.feeds[0].field1
      humidity = weatherData2.feeds[0].field2
      if (temp != null && temp != tempList[tempList.length - 1]) {
        tempList.push(temp);

      } else if (humidity != null && humidity != humidList[humidList.length - 1]) {
        humidList.push(humidity);
        theWeather.roomHumidity = humidity;
      }
    })

  })
}, 1000);
```

the api i get the data from is thingspeak (something like fireBase) which is connected to a node mcu
i think this method is wrong , becuase i constantly make a http.get request , is there a better aproach  ?

Comment: You shouldn't use `else if` for pushing humidity. That's used for a series of mutually exclusive conditions. Your code will not save the humidity whenever there's a new temperature.

Comment: Is it OK that `tempList` and `humidList` are not in sync? What if the temperature stays the same but humidity changes, or vice versa? You'll add to one array but not the other.

Comment: Other that these details, your general approach of using `setInterval()` to call the API periodically is reasonable.

Comment: then i should use another if statement , right?

Comment: Right. It should be a standalone `if` statement, not `else if`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) for this if you are able to change the API.